# Why is my Apple Watch Simulator black?

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch

I have a requirement to create a watchkit app.
Please let me know if it is possible to create a separate app with watch kit or do we have to do this with extensions.

I am testing my application in a simulator. The iPhone simulator and the Apple watch simulator both are coming up. The Apple watch simulator is black, no screen is coming up. 
My System harddisk : 320 GB , RAM : 5 GB.

Comment: Did you put something on interface.storyboard....???

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't read this already, have a look at it. In short it looks like you can only achieve this using extensions at the moment.

[This article](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/) explains what they expect from you as a 3rd party watch app developer.

> Apple Watch requires the presence of an iPhone to run third-party apps. To create a third-party app, you need two separate bundles: a WatchKit app (that runs on Apple Watch) and a WatchKit extension (that runs on the user’s iPhone). The WatchKit app contains only the storyboards and resource files associated with your app’s user interface. The WatchKit extension contains the code for managing the WatchKit app’s user interface and for responding to user interactions.

Also

> Because a WatchKit app extends the behavior of your existing iOS app, the WatchKit app and WatchKit extension are bundled together and packaged inside your iOS app bundle. During installation of your iOS app, the system prompts the user to install the WatchKit app when a paired Apple Watch is present.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to develop standalone WatchKit app. As you said - it has to be an extension. Also your iPhone app has to do something - it can not be just a container for your extension.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.Can you please let me know why my Apple watch 42 mm simulator is black?

Comment: Have you created your view in storyboard?

Answer (score 0):

Watch Apps have to be set up as App extensions and cannot be created as stand-alone apps. This is just not what Apple has designed the Watch for, rather view it as an additional screen of your iOS device. Apple also recommends to have as much of your ressource-intensive code as possible in the main iOS-App - e.g. background tasks.

As to why your screen is black:
Make sure you are building the Watch App-Scheme. Then even if your Watch app does not have any UI elements yet, you should see the time in the upper right corner of the watch simulator.